# Boost:spirit Parsing into structure and reusing parts of it

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have to find variables in a sentence and replace them by their value. Variables can be written in different forms, like $varName, or $(varName) for example.

I'd like to have a struct VariableHolder to have easy access to both :

```
struct VariableHolder
{
    string name;    // contains "varName"
    string fromFile;  // contains "$(varName)" or "$varName"
    void setName(ustring n) { name = n; }
}
```

Obviously, I'd like to avoid doing multiple passes and calling multiple parsers.
What I have so far is this :

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(VariableHolder,
(ustring, fromFile)
)
// variableName is another parser that returns a string
qi::rule<Iterator, VariableHolder()> variable %=
                (qi::char_("$")
                    >> (variableName[phoenix::bind(&VariableHolder::setName, qi::_val, qi::_1)]
                        | (qi::char_("(")
                            >> variableName[phoenix::bind(&VariableHolder::setName, qi::_val, qi::_1)]
                            >> qi::char_(")")))
                    );
```

Which doesn't work. The name is correctly set, but the fromFile variable only contains a "$", and never anything else.

So, my questions to you fine folk :

1. My idea was to only adapt part of the structure with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT, and fill the rest with semantic actions. Stupid idea, or am I just doing it wrong?
2. Is there a way to bind a semantic action and still get the output? Like

   char_[doSomething] // Can this both call doSomething, and parse a char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the questions:

> 1. My idea was to only adapt part of the structure with `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`, and fill the rest with semantic actions. Stupid idea, or am I just doing it wrong?

Not unthinkable. Not my recommendation (see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)). But yeah you're doing it wrong:

You want `lit("$")` instead of `char_("$")` if you don't want it to be part of the exposed attribute. In fact, `'$'` will do here

> 2. Is there a way to bind a semantic action and still get the output? Like
>
>    ```
>    char_[doSomething] // Can this both call doSomething, and parse a char?
>    ```

Yes. You're doing it right now, and it works because of `operator%=` you used instead of `operator=` (see the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics).

However, it seems you are really trying to use the same input twice (raw as `fromFile` and "cooked" as `name`?)  it backfires, because the auto-rule attribute propagation *also* overwrites `name` with the value you want for `fromFile`.

The only quick way out, here, is to use SA only. I'd suggest making `VariableHolder`'s constructor responsible for details though.

> Side note: it looks a bit as if the optional parentheses suggest an expression grammar. If so, make that explicit in the grammar, instead of hardcoding a special case in the rule for a `variableName`. If not, carry on :)

Here's an attempted fix:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/122b36f7c112d921)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct VariableHolder {
    std::string name;     // contains "varName"
    std::string fromFile; // contains "$(varName)" or "$varName"
};

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::ascii::space_type> struct P : qi::grammar<It, VariableHolder(), Skipper> {
    P() : P::base_type(start) {
        auto _name     = phoenix::bind(&VariableHolder::name, qi::_val);
        auto _fromFile = phoenix::bind(&VariableHolder::fromFile, qi::_val);

        variableName = qi::alpha >> +qi::alnum;
        variable = '$' >> (variableName | '(' >> variableName >> ')');

        start = qi::as_string [ qi::raw [ 
                variable [ _name = qi::_1 ]] 
            ] [ _fromFile = qi::_1 ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(variable)(variableName))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> variable;
    qi::rule<It, VariableHolder(), Skipper> start;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> variableName;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    P<It> const p;

    for (std::string const input : { 
            "$foo1",
            "$(bar2)" 
        }) 
    {
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        VariableHolder data;

        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::ascii::space, data);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parse success: " << data.name << " (source: '" << data.fromFile << "')\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failure ('" << input << "')\n";
        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success: foo1 (source: '$foo1')
Parse success: bar2 (source: '$(bar2)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, in great detail as always :)
 But I think my mind just broke. How come you can get two different outputs of one rule? I'm guessing that by using `operator=` you only get the parsers, and qi::raw gives you the complete output?
How would that work internally? Every rule stores both its "normal" and raw outputs?

Comment: Indeed, raw [] exposes the raw matched input sequence. The reason you can use both attributes is because of where the semantic action attaches. The first attaches at the sub parser expression (that exposes the name), and the `fromFile` action attaches to the result of the`raw []` directive itself

Comment: A proper qi::rule only _synthesises_ one attribute naturally (although it would be possible to synthesise a tuple of them from a custom directive like `with_raw`.